# How do I log out of Zeplin VSCode Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zeplin

I logged into the wrong account for Zeplin VSCode extension. I tried uninstalling, reinstalling, and restarting VSCode. The account information is saved. I don't see anything in the settings that would allow me to logout and re-login.

Comment: Have you gone to the command bar and typed `Zeplin:` to see if a sign out or log out command intellisense option appears? That's often how you have to log out of VS Code extensions. Unless that's what you mean by 'settings' (rather than Settings.json)?

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, go to `View > Command Palette` and write `zeplin.logout`.

Then, you can click on `Zeplin: Log Out from Zeplin`.